# Android app is not showing installed on emulator and my device

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, android-manifest

I have tried converted my android app from eclipse to android studio project and app is working on testing on emulator and my real device but I couldn't find it when trying to exit the app .. After publishing to the store I got the same issue + app is never open .. after installing I just got uninstall only on google play store .. please help :)

this is app url to the store : **https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.linkedtalents.app&hl=en**

Here is my **manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.linkedtalents.app"
android:versionCode="10"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/launch123"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true" >
  <activity
  android:name="com.linkedtalents.app.Splash"
  android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:configChanges="locale"
  >
```

Comment: Mean, its icon is not showing or what?

Comment: yes, it's icon is not showing .. also after publishing app never open

Comment: Can you post the whole manifest?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you are missing the intent filter. at least you didnt post it. can you have a look that you have the MAIN LAUNCHER like here? you need exactly one activity that matches this, if you want to be started from a homescreen.

```
<activity
        android:name="..."
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```